# Vue mixin method is not defined on the instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm created global mixin in nuxt plugin

Plugin file:

```
const plugin= {};
plugin.install = function (Vue) {
  Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
      globalMethod (path) {
        return `//` + path;
      }
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(plugin);

export default plugin;
```

Problem:
The method succesely called from template, from @click event etc but when i try call it in src attribute it generate error:

> Cannot read property 'globalMethod' of undefined

Example:

```
<img :src="globalMethod(image.path)">
```

So i try define the same method in component and it's work ok.
But i need to use that method in all components

UPD1:

Component object (by using vue dev tools):

[image]

So mixin method "globalMethod" is availible.